# Storing elements in an unordered_set vs storing them in an unordered_map

Tags: c++, data-structures, unordered-map, unordered-set

Suppose I have the following User struct:

```
struct User { 
    string userId; 
    UserType userType; // UserType is just an enumeration
    string hostName;
    string ipAddress;
    //and more other attributes will be added here

};
```

and I need to store a collection of user records (around 10^5 users, can scale higher too ). Would it be better in performance if I store it as an unordered_set or unordered_map? Unordered_set is technically the same as HashSet, and unordered_map is the same as HashMap, right? Using a regular set (ordered) is not an option, as insertion and deletion will get very slow when the number of elements increase.

```
unordered_set <User> userRecords;
```

OR

```
unordered_map <string, User> userRecords; // string is the user ID.
```

I need it to be very fast in terms of insertion, deletion, and to access a particular user object by its userId.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would choose `unordered_map`, because I can get a user, given a userid at any time, without any extra work, while with `unordered_set` I don't have this facility.

As for the mentioned operations, the speed will be almost same.

Answer (score 6):

Since the `unordered_set<>` doesn't give you the possibility to easily access a user by his userId, `unordered_map<>` seems to be the correct choice.

Answer (score 6):

If performance is a significant concern then you'll probably want to profile and see which one performs better. Otherwise, choose the one that most logically describes what you're trying to do. [With only 100K items I think `set` and `map` may yet have acceptable performance if you need ordering somewhere else]